# Switch from linux user to administrator; how to setup and maintain identical installations

Tags: linux

I recently installed Linux on my computer at university. I do have Linux on my laptop and in the near future on my workstation. Additionally some of my colleagues who are doing similar computations may benefit from Linux too. I do need special software e.g Anaconda python with different packages installed. Some config files and symlinks in my home folders are also important. I do not want to setup the system each time from scratch.

How is this done by system administrators ?

Comment: This [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2724/best-way-to-clone-an-installation-copying-to-identical-hardware) was closed but still has good answer

Comment: I do not necessarily have identical hardware

Comment: Configure your system so the applications are on another partition.  This way you can only clone that and easily reconfigure each system if thats the case.